# How to get @param text in Java?

Tags: java, parameters

What I have is this code, and I would like to get the text after each `@param`.
Now, I have looked around on the web and I know that `@param` is only used by Javadoc for documentation, but is there maybe a way to prevent this, so that the text can be accesses inside the code, or maybe a way to circumvent this and get a similar result?

The class is a .class file by the way, so it is already complied and I can't really decompile it, because this is just an example and I would like to apply this to many more classes.

```
class Test {

    Test () {

    }

    /**
    * @param x left rigth
    * @param y up down
    */
    public NeVector set(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = 0;
        return this;
    }
}
```

What I was hoping for was something like:

```
Method[] m = Test.getClass().getMethods();
String[][] paramText = new String[0][];
for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    paramText[i] = (String[])m[i].getParamTexts(); 
    //sort of //returning all the @param 's for this 
    //method
}
```

But I couldn't find anything close to this (actually nothing that could get this at all... I also tried with the Annotation class (I have no idea if that has to do with one another, but apparently not...) But got nowhere.

If anyone knows any way to get the text from the `@param` notes, even if it's a real workaround, as long as I don't have to change the source material, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24728487/750510, https://tomassetti.me/extracting-javadoc-documentation-source-files-using-javaparser/

Comment: @madhead Thanks, looks like that is exactly what i was searching for. Now i just need to figure out how to use it.